# GIT Bash, npm start error

Tags: npm, package-managers

i am getting the following error on npm start command,

> angular-quickstart@1.0.0 prestart C:\Project\myapp
>   npm run build
>
> angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build C:\Project\myapp
>   tsc -p src/
>
> angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start C:\Project\myapp
>   concurrently "npm run build:watch" "npm run serve"

Error occured when executing command: npm run build:watch
 Error: Unable to detect platform shell type. Please set SHELL_EXECUTE_FLAG env variable.
     at detectExecuteFlag (C:\Project\myapp\node_modules\spawn-default-shell\src\get-shell.js:29:9)
     at getShell (C:\Project\myapp\node_modules\spawn-default-shell\src\get-shell.js:37:18)
     at Object.spawn (C:\Project\myapp\node_modules\spawn-default-shell\src\index.js:5:24)
     at C:\Project\myapp\node_modules\concurrently\src\main.js:192:34
     at arrayMap (C:\Project\myapp\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:660:23)
     at Function.map (C:\Project\myapp\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:9571:14)
     at run (C:\Project\myapp\node_modules\concurrently\src\main.js:181:22)
     at main (C:\Project\myapp\node_modules\concurrently\src\main.js:61:5)
     at Object. (C:\Project\myapp\node_modules\concurrently\src\main.js:421:1)
     at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
     at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
     at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
     at run (bootstrap_node.js:418:7)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v7.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `concurrently "npm run build:watch" "npm run serve"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start script 'concurrently "npm run build:watch" "npm run serve"'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-quickstart package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     concurrently "npm run build:watch" "npm run serve"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-quickstart
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Project\myapp\npm-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your nodejs refer to these answers:
[How do I update node and npm on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412129/how-do-i-update-node-and-npm-on-windows?rq=1)
If the error still persist use this link:
['concurently' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35811633/concurently-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-pro)